# server encodes is different from local computer when using play framework

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, playframework-2.0

I'm running a play framework application. I ran all the test on local PC and works smoothly.

**description of the app:**

upload a text file and same in a directory

but for some strange reason whenever I try to run the SAME code in AWS, some characters comes out as mushed up like

> â€"

here are the some specs between two:

- both local pc and server run same version of play
- local is Ubuntu 16.04 and server is ubuntu 12.04
- java version on local is java version "1.7.0_95" where as server is
  java version "1.7.0_79"

Here is a snapcode

```
....
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
FilePart upload = body.getFile("file");
File file = upload.getFile();
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, bytes);
return ok();
```

**NOTE:**

I've already checked the encoding the file that is getting uploaded, it is  **UTF-8**

My question is : why is the code works fine on local computer but messes up the encoding on the production server?

Comment: What are using to view the data on the server? If you're using a browser or a editor of some sort check the encoding on that. It might not be UTF-8.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar i used termianl to view, also downloaded the file to local  computer using different means (scp, dropbox, placed in apache /var/www) and etc

Comment: Check the encoding on your terminal. It should be UTF-8.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar local is `en_GB.UTF-8` and aws server is `en_US.UTF-8` . I really hope they are both the same, right?

Comment: You should try to set both to either `en_GB.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8`. Just to be sure. Also could you tell me which characters are shown wrong?